# Memory access error despite allocating memory properly

Tags: c++, memory-management, segmentation-fault, gdb

```
struct SourceInfo {
  const char *filename;
  int line, col;
};

struct Node;

struct Lexer {
private:
  
    FILE *File;
    std::string Filename;

    char* test;

    int Line;
    int Column;

    static const int MAX_LINE_LENGTH = 1024;

public:
    
    Lexer(FILE* in, const char* filename)
    {
        File = in;
        
        test = new char[strlen(filename)+1];
        strcpy(test, filename);
        
        Filename = std::string(test);
        Line = 0;
        Column = 0;
    }

    ~Lexer() {
        
    }

    Node *next() {
        return nullptr;
    }

    Node *peek() {
        return nullptr;
    }

    SourceInfo get_current_pos() {
        SourceInfo info;
        
        info.filename = Filename.c_str();
        info.line = Line;
        info.col = Column;
        return info;
    }
};

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Lexer API functions
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

struct Lexer *lexer_create(FILE *in, const char *filename) {
  return new Lexer(in, filename);
}

void lexer_destroy(struct Lexer *lexer) {
  delete lexer;
}

struct Node *lexer_next(struct Lexer *lexer) {
  return lexer->next();
}

struct Node *lexer_peek(struct Lexer *lexer) {
  return lexer->peek();
}

struct SourceInfo lexer_get_current_pos(struct Lexer *lexer) {
  return lexer->get_current_pos();
}

/* The setup function creates the test fixture. */
TestObjs* setup();

/* The cleanup function cleans up the test fixture. */
void cleanup(TestObjs* objs);

//Test functions
void testCreate(TestObjs* objs);
void testGetCurrentPosAtBeginning(TestObjs* objs);

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    if (argc > 2) {
        printf("Usage: %s [<test name>]\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    /*
     * If a command line argument is passed, it's the name
     * of the test to be executed.
     */
    if (argc == 2) {
        tctest_testname_to_execute = argv[1];
    }

    /*
     * Install test execution hook.
     * (Only test suites that need to do detailed monitoring or
     * reporting of test execution will need to do this.)
     */
    //tctest_on_test_executed = onTestExecuted;

    /*
     * Install completion hook.
     * (Only test suites that need to do something special
     * to report results really need to do this: TEST_FINI
     * generates a reasonable human-readable summary of
     * the executed tests.
     */
    //tctest_on_complete = onComplete;

    /* Prepare to run tests */
    TEST_INIT();

    /* Execute test functions */
    TEST(testCreate);
    TEST(testGetCurrentPosAtBeginning);
    /*
     * Report results: exits with nonzero exit code if
     * any test failed
     */
    TEST_FINI();
}

TestObjs* setup() {
    TestObjs* objs = malloc(sizeof(TestObjs));
    return objs;
}

void cleanup(TestObjs* objs) {
    lexer_destroy(objs->lexer);
    free(objs);
}

void testCreate(TestObjs* objs) {
    const char *filename = "testFile.txt\0";
    objs->filename = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(filename) + 1));
    strcpy(objs->filename, filename);
    FILE* in = fopen(objs->filename, "r");
    objs->lexer = lexer_create(in, objs->filename);
}

void testGetCurrentPosAtBeginning(TestObjs* objs) {
    
    struct SourceInfo info = lexer_get_current_pos(objs->lexer);
    ASSERT(info.line == 0);
    ASSERT(info.col == 0);
    ASSERT(strcmp(objs->filename, info.filename) == 0);
    free(info.filename);
    
}
```

For some reason, I am getting a segmentation fault in testGetCurrentPosAtBeginning function. I do not why this error is occurring because I managed the memory properly. I looked through GDB and was puzzled as to why this error is occurring.

To me, it looks like memory is going out of scope at the constructor but I am not sure. The test functions are based off of TCTest, a test framework for C.

Comment: Are you sure this is C? Seeing you use words like "constructor" and things like `std::string` make me strongly doubt.

Comment: I'm sure it's not.  Tags updated.

Comment: Why are you using C strings in a C++ program. Just use `std::string` consistently and you should have fewer problems.

Comment: Is setup supposed to call the constructor? Because it doesn't call the constructor.

Comment: The program is split into multiple files. TCTest is a C framework, so that is why I have a C API for the C++ code.

Answer (score 1):

> For some reason, I am getting a segmentation fault in
> testGetCurrentPosAtBeginning function. I do not why this error is
> occurring because I managed the memory properly.

It is occurring because you are *not* managing memory properly.

In particular, `testGetCurrentPosAtBeginning()` does this:

> ```
>     free(info.filename);
> ```

You must free only pointer values obtained from `malloc()` or another memory-allocation function, but if we trace the source of `info.filename`, it ultimately comes from

> ```
>         info.filename = Filename.c_str();
> ```

in method `Lexer::get_current_pos()`.  This is not a string you should attempt to free.

Comment: Thanks! GDB was showing the error was somewhere else. I still get a segmentation fault after fixing the free(info.filename); GDB says the error is at Filename.c_str()

Comment: Also, I cannot access member variables in the struct in GDB. Why is this occuring? Even when I make the variables of the struct public it still occurs.

Comment: @Labrockstar, the error at `Filename.c_str()` is almost certainly the same error I already pointed out.  The problem is the inappropriate `free()`, but it's eminently plausible that it doesn't manifest visible misbehavior until the next attempt to access to the erstwhile freed space, at `Filename.c_str()`.  Make sure you actually rebuilt the program after removing the `free()` call, and that the rebuilt version is the one you are testing.

Comment: If you cannot access member variables (and you are using appropriate gdb commands for doing so) then my guess would be that your program was built without debug information, or else that the debug information was subsequently stripped.

Comment: Debug information is there.It says there is a memory access error.

Comment: The debug information, if present, would not say whether there was an error, much less what kind.  It just provides extra information to tools such as debuggers, so that they can do things like look up data by symbolic name.  However, another possibility for why you cannot access the member variables via gdb is that they have been optimized away.  If you're going to run a program under a debugger then it's a good idea to build it with all optimizations disabled and debug info enabled.

Comment: Also, for memory errors specifically, you might find it useful to run your program under a tool specifically designed to look for such issues, such as valgrind.  It, too, will benefit you more if the executable is built with debug information and (to a lesser extent) without optimization.